# Running test case files(tst) as part of MSbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, testcase

I am using TFS 2010 and Visual Studio 2010. I have a build definition which points to my solution. The build runs overnight

I have a set of test case files(*.tst) and i would like my current build to include these as part of the build and to execute them overnight. The test case files are in source control

I read that i have to use MsTest.exe but unsure how to get started?

Can anyone point me please how i can get started on running the test case files as part of the build? Any examples please?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can have your test cases run. One way is to add an invoke process or Exec Command to your build project file or workflow.
Place the call to mstest in the AfterBuild target or workflow step. The other way would be to separate out the build and test cases into different builds.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

[How to: Configure and Run Scheduled Tests After Building Your Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182465%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Example of MSBuild with MSTest](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/cb87a184-6589-454b-bf1c-2e82771fc3aa)

*Based on your comments here is an update of something you can do to get more information about the error or to continue if you encounter an error. You do not need to check for the error code if you just want to stop on any error but if you do want to check the error code then you would do something like this:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<Message Text="Running tests..." />
<PropertyGroup Label="TestSuccessOrNot">
    <TestSuccessOrNot>5</TestSuccessOrNot>
</PropertyGroup>
<!-- Run MSTest exe-->
<Exec Command="cd ." IgnoreExitCode="False" ContinueOnError="ErrorAndContinue">
    <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot" />
</Exec>
<Message Text="ExitCode = $(TestSuccessOrNot)" />
<Error Condition="'$(TestSuccessOrNot)' != '0'" Text="Unit tests fail!" /> </Target>
```

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for sharing that. In my test project i have placed the following target in the csproj file like so:

Comment: Hi there,

Thanks for sharing that. In my test project i created a AfterBuildTarget in the testproject which is part of the solution.

I put a check to determine whether we get an exit code back of value of 1 meaning theres an error. If I do i use something called ErrorCondition. At the moment my build is failing and i would like to find out more information when a exit code of 1 is returned. Would you be able to assist? I can provide you my code but apparently its too long according to StackOverflow.

Comment: `code`
</Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="Running tests..."/>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <TestSuccessOrNot>1</TestSuccessOrNot>
    </PropertyGroup>
     <!-- Run MSTest exe-->
    <Exec Command='"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:..\..\..\..\_Libraries\Tests\MyTestProject.FunctionalTests.dll /runconfig:MyTestProject.FunctionalTests.config'>
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="TestSuccessOrNot"/>
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="$(TestSuccessOrNot) == 1" Text="Unit tests fail!" />
  </Target>
`code`

Any advice on the above?

Comment: You can add a ContinueOnError="ErrorAndContinue" if you want to hit additional steps in your target. I will post another answer so you can see what I am talking about.